# jQuery widget _on delegating Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I am using the Widget factory from jQuery UI into a existing production environment.

This environment uses a binded event called `sm2.validateNext` which triggers before the page changes. However when trying to bind to this event using `_on`, it would try to split this event name and delegate it. (Which i believe is correct, bot not the expected functionality for me).

Code (inside the $.widget):

```
this._on(true, document, {
    "sm2.validateNext": function () { ... },
});
```

And debugging this code, it gets delegated (not my expected behaviour) (from jquery-ui.widget.js)

```
var match = event.match( /^(\w+)\s*(.*)$/ ),
eventName = match[1] + instance.eventNamespace,
selector = match[2];
if ( selector ) {
    delegateElement.delegate( selector, eventName, handlerProxy );
} else {
    element.bind( eventName, handlerProxy );
}
```

Because of the . (dot) it gets a match and selector becomes valid delegating the event. However I need to get binded with its handlerProxy.

Is there a way to avoid get "trapped" into that match? I tried to escape sm2\.validateNext without result.

**Note:**

```
$(document).on("sm2.validateNext"...)
```

Doesnt work for me as I need the instance to be at the widget object.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution by using `$.proxy`

Instead of:

```
this._on(true, document, {
    "sm2.validateNext": function () { ... },
});
```

I used:

```
$(document).on("sm2.validateNext", $.proxy(function () { ... }, this));
```

And now it works just as I expected.